# Where can I get a list of all modules for apache2 and what they are for?

Tags: apache-2.2

For various reasons I would like to know more about the capabilities of Apache.
Since most of the server's functionality is provided by modules, is there a place where I can get a list of all the available modules (and what they do)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"All" modules is ambiguous; there's an enormous number of third-party modules out in the world, anyone can write one at any time.

For all the modules included in the project, see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/).

There's also an Apache-maintained registry of third party modules [here](https://modules.apache.org/).